# Scrape data from specific fields from ClinicalTrials.Gov

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written a function, which given a NCTID (i.e a ClinicalTrials.Gov ID) it scrapes data from ClinicalTrials.Gov:

```
def clinicalTrialsGov (nctid):
    data = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/" + nctid + "?displayxml=true").text, "xml")
    subset = ['intervention_type', 'study_type', 'allocation', 'intervention_model', 'primary_purpose', 'masking', 'enrollment', 'official_title', 'condition', 'minimum_age', 'maximum_age', 'gender', 'healthy_volunteers', 'phase', 'primary_outcome', 'secondary_outcome', 'number_of_arms']
    tag_matches = data.find_all(subset)
```

I then do the following:

```
tag_dict = dict((str('ct' + tag_matches[i].name.capitalize()), tag_matches[i].text) for i in range(0, len(tag_matches)))
for key in tag_dict:
    print(key + ': ' + tag_dict[key])
```

to convert this data into a dictionary. However, in cases where there are multiple intervention types (eg. [NCT02170532](http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT02170532)) this will only take one intervention type. How can I adapt this code so that when there are fiels with multiple values, the values are listed in a comma seperated list.

Current Output:

```
ctOfficial_title: Aerosolized Beta-Agonist Isomers in Asthma
ctPhase: Phase 4
ctStudy_type: Interventional
ctAllocation: Non-Randomized
ctIntervention_model: Crossover Assignment
ctPrimary_purpose: Treatment
ctMasking: None (Open Label)
ctPrimary_outcome: 
Change in Maximum Forced Expiratory Volume at One Second (FEV1)
Baseline (before treatment), 30 minutes, 1, 2, 4, 6, and 8 hours post treatment

ctSecondary_outcome: 
Change in Dyspnea Response as Measured by the University of California, San Diego (UCSD) Dyspnea Scale
Baseline (before treatment), 30 minutes, 1, 2, 4, 6, and 8 hours post treatment

ctNumber_of_arms: 5
ctEnrollment: 10
ctCondition: Asthma
ctIntervention_type: Drug
ctGender: All
ctMinimum_age: 18 Years
ctMaximum_age: N/A
ctHealthy_volunteers: No
```

Desired Output:

```
ctOfficial_title: Aerosolized Beta-Agonist Isomers in Asthma
ctPhase: Phase 4
ctStudy_type: Interventional
ctAllocation: Non-Randomized
ctIntervention_model: Crossover Assignment
ctPrimary_purpose: Treatment
ctMasking: None (Open Label)
ctPrimary_outcome: 
Change in Maximum Forced Expiratory Volume at One Second (FEV1)
Baseline (before treatment), 30 minutes, 1, 2, 4, 6, and 8 hours post treatment

ctSecondary_outcome: 
Change in Dyspnea Response as Measured by the University of California, San Diego (UCSD) Dyspnea Scale
Baseline (before treatment), 30 minutes, 1, 2, 4, 6, and 8 hours post treatment

ctNumber_of_arms: 5
ctEnrollment: 10
ctCondition: Asthma
ctIntervention_type: Drug, Drug, Other, Device, Device, Drug
ctGender: All
ctMinimum_age: 18 Years
ctMaximum_age: N/A
ctHealthy_volunteers: No
```

How can I adapt the code so that it will scrape all the intervention types?

Comment: Could you add what you expect as output?

Comment: For the id you have given, I see 6 `intervention_type` fields. Tested using bs4 `4.6.0`

Comment: @bla Please see edit.

Comment: @MartinEvans Please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was failing as it was overwriting previous values for a given dictionary key. Instead you need to append to an existing entry.

You can make use of Python's `defaultdict()`. This can be used to automatically create lists for each of the keys. If there are multiple entries, each one is appended to the list for that key. Then when printing, the list can be joined back together with `,` separators if needed:

```
import bs4
from collections import defaultdict    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import requests

def clinicalTrialsGov(nctid):
    data = defaultdict(list)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/" + nctid + "?displayxml=true").text, "xml")
    subset = ['intervention_type', 'study_type', 'allocation', 'intervention_model', 'primary_purpose', 'masking', 'enrollment', 'official_title', 'condition', 'minimum_age', 'maximum_age', 'gender', 'healthy_volunteers', 'phase', 'primary_outcome', 'secondary_outcome', 'number_of_arms']

    for tag in soup.find_all(subset):
        data['ct{}'.format(tag.name.capitalize())].append(tag.get_text(strip=True))

    for key in data:
        print('{}: {}'.format(key, ', '.join(data[key])))

clinicalTrialsGov('NCT02170532')
```

This would display the following:

```
ctOfficial_title: Aerosolized Beta-Agonist Isomers in Asthma
ctPhase: Phase 4
ctStudy_type: Interventional
ctAllocation: Non-Randomized
ctIntervention_model: Crossover Assignment
ctPrimary_purpose: Treatment
ctMasking: None (Open Label)
ctPrimary_outcome: Change in Maximum Forced Expiratory Volume at One Second (FEV1)Baseline (before treatment), 30 minutes, 1, 2, 4, 6, and 8 hours post treatment
ctSecondary_outcome: Change in 8 Hour Area-under-the-curve FEV10 to 8 hours post dose, Change in Heart RateBaseline (before treatment), 30 minutes, 1, 2, 4, 6, and 8 hours post treatment, Change in Tremor Assessment Measured by a ScaleBaseline (before treatment), 30 minutes, 1, 2, 4, 6, and 8 hours post treatmentTremor assessment will be made on outstretched hands (0 = none, 1+ = fine tremor, barely perceptible, 2+ = obvious tremor)., Change in Dyspnea Response as Measured by the University of California, San Diego (UCSD) Dyspnea ScaleBaseline (before treatment), 30 minutes, 1, 2, 4, 6, and 8 hours post treatment
ctNumber_of_arms: 5
ctEnrollment: 10
ctCondition: Asthma
ctIntervention_type: Drug, Drug, Other, Device, Device, Drug
ctGender: All
ctMinimum_age: 18 Years
ctMaximum_age: N/A
ctHealthy_volunteers: No
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is last tag value as all the previous values will override by the next value. You need to check if a key already exists in dictionary and if so handle is accordingly.
Something like this :

```
tag_dict = {}
for i in range(0, len(tag_matches)):
    if(str('ct' + tag_matches[i].name.capitalize())) in tag_dict:
         tag_dict[str('ct' + tag_matches[i].name.capitalize())] += ', '+tag_matches[i].text
    else:
         tag_dict[(str('ct' + tag_matches[i].name.capitalize()))]= tag_matches[i].text
```